# Insert into Multiple Tables using PHP with LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is the code that I've tried but I can't seem to make the right tweaks to get the script to run properly.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES('.$_POST['first_name'].', '.$_POST['last_name'].', '.$_POST['email'].')
INSERT INTO client_data (client_id, phone, zip, note) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '.$_POST['phone'].', '.$_POST['zip'].', '.$_POST['message'].')';

mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Side note: what happens when `Jimmy O'Brian` makes an order?

Comment: Or Little Bobby Tables? (http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario The hackers win, that's what happens. Remember to sanitize your input!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute two sql statements with `mysql_query();`

Use something like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES('.$_POST['first_name'].', '.$_POST['last_name'].', '.$_POST['email'].')';
mysql_query($sql);

$clientId = mysql_insert_id();

$sql = 'INSERT INTO client_data (client_id, phone, zip, note) VALUES('.$clientId.', '.$_POST['phone'].', '.$_POST['zip'].', '.$_POST['message'].')';

mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

But *please* read up on SQL injections and how to prevent them.

Answer (score 0):

You should break it up into two separate `mysql_query` calls and use the `mysql_insert_id` function:

```
$firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["first_name"]);
$lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["last_name"]);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]);
$zip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["zip"]);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["message"]);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('{$firstName}', '{$lastName}', '{$email}')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO client_data (client_id, phone, zip, note) VALUES ('". mysql_insert_id() ."', '{$phone}', '{$zip}', '{$message}')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make 2 queries:

```
$sql_insert_clients = "INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES(".$_POST['first_name'].", ".$_POST['last_name'].", ".$_POST['email'].")";
mysql_query($sql_insert_clients) or die (mysql_error());

$sql_insert_client_data = "INSERT INTO client_data (client_id, phone, zip, note) VALUES(".mysql_insert_id().", ".$_POST['phone'].", ".$_POST['zip'].", ".$_POST['message'].")";
mysql_query($sql_insert_client_data) or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -1):

Your just missing the semi-colon to split the Insert's

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, email) 
        VALUES('.$_POST['first_name'].', '.$_POST['last_name'].', '.$_POST['email'].')'."; ".' INSERT INTO client_data (client_id, phone, zip, note) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '.$_POST['phone'].', '.$_POST['zip'].', '.$_POST['message'].')';

mysqli_multi_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

the SQL query it should be running (with dummy content) is

```
INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES('test', 'surname', email); INSERT INTO client_data (client_id, phone, zip, note) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'phone', 'zip', 'message');
```

Comment: I've just tested this in a dummy mysql db.. it does indeed work.

Comment: It is possible with [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), but not with [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Comment: Sorry, you're right, what I meant was it does not work with PHP's `mysql_query()`, apologies.

Comment: Ahh, no problem. Yes, was only able to test the SQL locally, not with PHP. @ejay, Going with Travesty's option with the cleaning of the Post variables is the best way.